# Camel 2.14 initialization fills up with connections to rabbitMQ until it crashes

Tags: java, apache-camel, rabbitmq, guice

I have a program where it used to work with camel 2.13 and since I upgraded it to 2.14 it crashes at initialization, when the endpoints to rabbitMQ are created. The debug I made showed me that there are lots of threads being created, also on rabbitMQ interface i can see the connections growing from 24 to 1000+ in matter of seconds.

example of one rabbitmq uri:
rabbitmq://server1:5672/naop?username=xx&password=yy&addresses=server1:5672,server2:5672,server3:5672&queue=theResponse&routingKey=response&autoAck=true&prefetchCount=10&autoDelete=false

Any clue? thanks!

PS: Well, after a few try outs, its not about rabbitMQ, it's every endpoint I try to initialize with JndiBind (camel guice), it just loops over creating endpoints until it goes out of memory.

Comment: Is this for a producer? In Camel 2.14.1 they introduced changes to RabbitMQProducer to use a pool of threads based on this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7421. This was not present in 2.13.X so maybe some of those changes are breaking your stuff. Can you provide more details about your exact scenario to see if it can be reproduce?

Comment: Yes, it is for producer. I believe your description is exactly what's breaking my software, any idea on how to revert that scenario? I really need the old behavior and also need the new camel options.. Thank you!!

Comment: Well, after a few try outs, its not about rabbitMQ, it's every endpoint I try to initialize with JndiBind (camel guice), it just loops over creating endpoints until it goes out of memory.